# Future of JSON with Padding (JSONP)

Tags: security, browser, jsonp

I am trying to find out the 'long-term' support for JSONP by browsers.
I’ve been reading some articles and they all tell that JSONP if not implemented correctly could contain some serious vulnerabilities, but still JSONP is used by a lot of people/companies.

Is there any information to find about the future of JSONP and its support by browsers?

Answer (score 0):

JSONP does not depend on specific browser support. The "padding" or function callback makes valid JavaScript of the JSON, so browsers only need support for generic JavaScript to support JSONP. So I expect JSONP to be keep working for a very long time.

The feature of JSONP is that it can expose data to another website. This can also be a security risk, in that it exposes data to malicious websites.

A more modern alternative is to use [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), which has similar security risks if not configured correctly.